# How to catch Errno::ECONNRESET class in "case when"?

Tags: ruby, exception, case, errno

My application (Ruby 1.9.2) may raise different exceptions, including net-connection breaks. I `rescue Exception => e`, then do `case/when` to handle them in defferent ways, but several errors go through my cases straight to `else`.

```
rescue Exception => e
    p e.class
    case e.class
        when Errno::ECONNRESET
            p 1
        when Errno::ECONNRESET,Errno::ECONNABORTED,Errno::ETIMEDOUT
            p 2
        else
            p 3
    end
end
```

Prints:

```
Errno::ECONNRESET
3
```

Comment: Rescue your error classes in a multi-rescue block and then you can avoid the case statement entirely.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

This is because of how the `===` operator works on the class `Class`

The `case` statement [internally calls](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000345) the `===` method on the object you are evaluating against. If you want to test for `e` class, you just test against `e`, not `e.class`. That's because `e.class` would fall into the `when Class` case, because, well, e.class is a Class.

```
rescue Exception => e
    case e
        when Errno::ECONNRESET
            p 1
        when Errno::ECONNRESET,Errno::ECONNABORTED,Errno::ETIMEDOUT
            p 2
        else
            p 3
    end
end
```

Yeah, Ruby can have weird semantics sometimes

Comment: Yeah, weird. 1 === 1 => true. Array === Array => false.

Comment: Uh. I'd bet `Array === Class` would give true, but now I'm confused. Thanks to your comment now I can't sleep :/

Comment: Of course, now it makes sense. The `===` is called on the element you're comparing to. So `Class === Array`, `String === "foobar"` and `/foo/ === "foobar"` all return true.

Answer (score 3):

Well it depends upon whether you referencing the class or the constant.
I have for instance had to use the following case statement to get a certain type of detection working

```
def fail(exception_error)
exception = exception_error
case exception.class
  when /HTTPClient::ConnectTimeoutError.new/
    status = 'CONNECTION TIMEOUT'
    connection_status = 'DOWN'
  else
    status = 'UNKNOWN FAILURE'
    connection_status = 'DOWN'
end
```

But that's because I'm working with the actual Exception Class not the constant.
HTTPCLient is raising an actual class object:

```
class TimeoutError < RuntimeError
end  
class ConnectTimeoutError < TimeoutError
end
```

Here's a puzzling fact:

```
error = HTTPClient::ConnectTimeoutError.new
HTTPClient::ConnectTimeoutError === error
#=> true
error === HTTPClient::ConnectTimeoutError
#=> false
```

Not sure what to make of that.

Comment: what version of ruby was the 'puzzling fact' run in?