# Ruby class types and case statements

Tags: ruby, duck-typing, case-statement

What is the difference between

```
case item.class
when MyClass
  # do something here
when Array
  # do something different here
when String
  # do a third thing
end
```

and

```
case item.class
when MyClass.class
  # do something here
when Array.class
  # do something different here
when String.class
  # do a third thing
end
```

For some reason, the first one of these works sometimes and the second doesn't, and other times, the second one works and the first one doesn't.  Why?  Which one is the "proper" way to do it?

Comment: String is a class. The class of a class is Class.

Comment: Note that `MyClass === obj` uses the [Module#===](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Module.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) method to check if `obj` is an instance of `MyClass`.

Comment: None of the answers make sense to me. From my experiments, it just looks like using class objects in a when/case structure actually compare to the value's class rather than the value itself.

Answer (score 285, accepted):

You must use:

```
case item
when MyClass
...
```

I had the same problem:
[How to catch Errno::ECONNRESET class in "case when"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801469/how-to-catch-errnoeconnreset-class-in-case-when)

Comment: Thanks!  Sorry to dupe (or sort of dupe), but several searches didn't turn up that previous question.  It seems that the use of === by the case statement is quite a common problem, now that I see this is the problem.  This should probably be pointed out more often in tutorials and such (but I bet that many tutorial writers aren't aware of this either).

Comment: A caveat that hasn't been mentioned if using ActiveRecord. The ActiveRecord === method on class comparisons uses .is_a?, which means that subclasses of a class will evaluate to true in the case statement. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/04cda1848cb847c2bdad0bfc12160dc8d5547775/activerecord/lib/active_record/core.rb#L135

Comment: Yes, this is not working with ActiveModel either, a pretty big gotcha!

Answer (score 78):

Yeah, Nakilon is correct, you must know how the threequal === operator works on the object given in the `when` clause.  In Ruby

```
case item
when MyClass
...
when Array
...
when String
...
```

is really

```
if MyClass === item
...
elsif Array === item
...
elsif String === item
...
```

Understand that case is calling a threequal method (`MyClass.===(item)` for example), and that method can be defined to do whatever you want, and then you can use the case statement with precisionw

Comment: If I have `arr = []` then I noticed that `if Array === arr` will evaluate to true but `if arr === Array` will evaluate to false. Can someone please help explain?

Comment: === is just a method that can be defined to do whatever the designer of a class wants it to do. Remember, also, that a === b really means a.=== b, so if you switch a and b around, you can get different behavior. There is no guarantee that === is commutative. In fact, Array === Array is false, but Object === Object is true, so Array is redefining the semantics of ===.

Answer (score 26):

You can use:

```
case item.class.to_s
    when 'MyClass'
```

...when the following twist is not possible:

```
case item
    when MyClass
```

The reason for this is that `case` uses `===`, and [the relationship the `===` operator describes is **not commutative**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4528453/664833). For example, `5` is an `Integer`, but is `Integer` a `5`? This is how you should think of `case`/`when`.

Comment: "5 is an Integer, but is Integer a 5" is a wonderfully human explanation, thank you.

Answer (score 7):

In Ruby, a class name is a constant that refers to an object of type `Class` that describes a particular class. That means that saying `MyClass` in Ruby is equivalent to saying `MyClass.class` in Java.

`obj.class` is an object of type `Class` describing the class of `obj`. If `obj.class` is `MyClass`, then `obj` was created using `MyClass.new` (roughly speaking). `MyClass` is an object of type `Class` that describes any object created using `MyClass.new`.

`MyClass.class` is the class of the `MyClass` object (it's the *class* of the object of type `Class` that describes any object created using `MyClass.new`). In other words, `MyClass.class == Class`.

Comment: Ah! This makes sense now that I've learned more about Ruby metaprogramming.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the nature of your `item` variable. If it is an instance of an object, e.g.

```
t = 5
```

then

```
t.class == Fixnum
```

but if it is a class in itself e.g

```
t = Array
```

then it will be a `Class` object, so

```
t.class == Class
```

**EDIT**: please refer to [How to catch Errno::ECONNRESET class in "case when"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801469/how-to-catch-errnoeconnreset-class-in-case-when) as stated by Nakilon since my answer could be wrong.

Comment: In Ruby,  everything is "an instance of an object".