# How to check in Ruby if method's parameter is a symbol?

Tags: ruby

```
def my_method(parameter)
  if <what should be here?>
    puts "parameter is a string"
  elsif <and here?>
    puts "parameter is a symbol"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The simplest form would be:

```
def my_method(parameter)
  puts "parameter is a #{parameter.class}"
end
```

But if you actually want to do some processing based on type do this:

```
def my_method(parameter)
  puts "parameter is a #{parameter.class}"
  case parameter
    when Symbol
      # process Symbol logic
    when String
      # process String logic
    else
      # some other class logic
   end
end
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `case parameter.class`?

Comment: @Beerlington I just tested, and it works fine using only parameter.

Comment: @Beerlington: No: in a `case x; when y ....; end`, Ruby runs `y === x` to determine if it should enter the `when` block.  `===` is just defined to do something "useful"; for instance, for classes, it's `instance_of?`; for ranges, it's `include?`, etc.

Comment: Some more [insight](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908380/ruby-class-types-and-case-statements) into `case parameter.class` issue.

Answer (score 25):

```
def my_method(parameter)
  if parameter.is_a? String
    puts "parameter is a string"
  elsif parameter.is_a? Symbol
    puts "parameter is a symbol"
  end
end
```

should solve your issue

Answer (score 14):

```
if parameter.is_a? String
  puts "string"
elsif parameter.is_a? Symbol
  puts "symbol"
end
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
def my_method(parameter)
  if parameter.is_a? String
    puts "parameter is a string"
  elsif parameter.is_a? Symbol
    puts "parameter is a symbol"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if parameter.respond_to? id2name
      p "Symbol"
else
     p "not a symbol"
```

This will also work , but not an elegant solution.