# 3 Equals or Case Equality operator

Tags: ruby, equality, commutativity

In Ruby `Integer === 5` returns `true`. Similarly `String === "karthik"` returns `true`.
However, `5 === Integer` returns `false`. And `"karthik" === String`.
Why is the operator not commutative?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The simple answer is: because it doesn't make sense. The relationship the operator describes is not commutative, why should the operator be?

Just look at your own examples: `5` is an `Integer`. But is `Integer` a `5`? What does that even *mean*?

`===` is the *case subsumption operator*, and subsumption doesn't commute.

The fact that the case subsumption operator uses equals signs, and that it is usually called the *triple equals*, `threequals` or `case equality` operator is *terribly* unfortunate since it not only has *absolutely nothing* to do with equality, but it also does not conform to many of the laws that equality conforms to, such as transitivity and as you mentioned commutativity.

For more of my ranting about `===` see

- [What does the `===` operator do in Ruby?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/4467538/#4467823)
- [`===` vs. `==` in Ruby](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/3422223/#3422349)
- [How does `Integer === 3` work?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/2030417/#2030586)

Answer (score 7):

One very simple reason is that the `is_a?` relationship for classes just can't be commutative. Consider the case where both operands are classes:

```
Class === String
```

This will return true because `String.is_a?(Class)`. However `String === Class` will return false, because `Class.is_a?(String)` is false and that is of course as it should be.

Another reason is that the semantics of `===` depends on its left operand. This has again two reasons: a) In ruby the semantics always depend on the left operand, because the left operand is the receiver of the method call and b) it is useful, so you can use e.g. classes, ranges and regexen in a case statement with the intended semantics.

Answer (score 2):

Many operators are not commutative.

The `===` is called the "case equality operator" because it is called when branching is a case.

It is nice and useful that:

```
foo = 42
case foo
when Integer
  # branches here
when String
  # etc...
end
```

It would not be very useful if

```
foo = Integer
case foo
when 42
# would branch here??
when 666
# etc...
end
```

Note that in Ruby 1.9, the `===` operator on a Proc/lambda will call that Proc:

```
divisible_by_three = ->(x){x % 3 == 0}
divisible_by_three === 42 # => true
```

Again, very useful in a `case` statement, but not much in the reverse order.

Answer (score 1):

#### it needs to implement case-when comparisons

It's normal to have non-commutative operators.

```
/ - % [] . -> ^ << >> < <= > >= && || = += -= ,
```

And as it happens, `===` exists in part as the *case-when* operator. That's rather elaborate in Ruby, and it couldn't be so if it had to be simplified to a commutative op.