# Check if of a certain class with case/when

Tags: ruby

Why do I get "thumbs down"?

```
p = Post.new  

case p.class
when Post
  "Thumbs up"
else
  "Thumbs down"
end
```

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to check classes specifically. Check instances, this is how case works.

```
p = Post.new  

case p
when Post
  "Thumbs up"
else
  "Thumbs down"
end
```

"I have this thing `p`, what might it be? Is it a Post or maybe a string that conforms to this regex? Or some another thing?"

More info on threequals operator, the power behind ruby's case expression: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4528453/125816

Comment: This is the correct way to do it. IMHO all the other answers should be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

"p.class" is the class, not the class name, try "p.class.name" instead.

Comment: yeah, he's not checking for class names.