# Enumerable#grep with a custom ruby class

Tags: ruby

I'm on Ruby 3.2 and I have a custom class `Foo` that (for demonstration purposes) stores an array of values.

I have another code part that is not under my control, that uses `Enumerable#grep` and `Enumerable#grep_v` to search for string patterns in an array.

I want to make the `Foo` class work with `Array#grep`. I looked into https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep and it states that

> With no block given, returns an array containing each element for which pattern === element is true:

I tried implementing a `#===` method like this

```
class Foo
  def initialize(values)
    @values = values
  end

  def ===(pattern)
    @values.any? { |v| v.match?(pattern) }
  end
end
```

But this doesn't seem to work:

```
[Foo.new(["foo", "bar"]), Foo.new(["zoo"])].grep(/oo/)
=> []
```

I can also see, when I put a debugger or puts statement inside `def ===(pattern)` that it does not seem to be called by the grep command.

Any idea on how this could work?

Comment: Read the docs again. Hint: which object is on the left and right hand side of the operator?

Comment: Ahhhh ok, that means that I would have to build a custom pattern class with it's own `#===` method that can handle my `Foo` items, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look closely at [the documentation of `Enumerable#grep`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep) [***bold italic*** emphasis mine]:

> ## `grep(pattern)` → `array`
>
> ## `grep(pattern) {|element| ... }` → `array`
>
> Returns an array of objects based elements of `self` that match the given pattern.
>
> With no block given, returns an array containing each element for which ***`pattern === element`*** is true […]

The *pattern* is on the left-hand side of the [`===` triple-equals *case subsumption* binary infix operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3422349/2988), which means the message `===` is sent to the *pattern*, not to the *element*. The `===` triple-equals *case subsumption* binary infix operator is [not commutative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4528453/2988).

If you want your object to be matchable by a [`Regexp`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/Regexp.html), then you need to represent it as something that can be matched by a `Regexp`, i.e., a [`String`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/String.html):

```ruby
class Foo
  def initialize(values)
    @values = values
  end

  def to_str = @values.join
end

[Foo.new(%w[foo bar]), Foo.new(['zoo'])].grep(/oo/)
#=> [#<Foo:0xdeadbeef @values=["foo", "bar"]>, #<Foo:0xdeadbeef @values=["zoo"]>]
```

But, please, *only* do this *if your object actually [**IS-A**](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) string*, i.e., if it can be considered to be a subtype / specialization of a string.

The "three letter" conversion methods (`to_str`, `to_int`, `to_ary`, `to_float`, `to_hash`, etc., and yes, I know they're not all three letters) should *only* be implemented for objects which *genuinely* are [*subtypes*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping). I.e., `to_str` should only be implemented by objects which are *subtypes* of `String` (the object **IS-A** string), but for technical reasons cannot be *subclasses* of `String`.

If you look at which objects implement `to_str` in the Ruby core library, you will find that there are only three, `String` and two others, and I would argue the two others are *wrong* and *shouldn't* implement it. Same goes for `to_int` or `to_float`. These should be *very* judiciously used.

They are used for *implicit conversions*, with all the dangers that entails. If you implement `Foo#to_str`, you should be very sure that you really want `Foo` to be silently converted to `String` *everywhere* where a `String` is expected, and not, say, `raise` an `Exception` instead.

All this is to say: trying to match something with a `Regexp` that is not a `String` is weird. Are you sure that is what you want, or is there maybe something in your design that isn't quite right?

Comment: Alternatively, you could also implement a custom pattern class (right-hand side) to match Foo instances via `grep`.

Comment: @Stefan I would add, and argue, that it would be better to implement a collection class for `Foo`s (and other domain specific objects) and implement your own form of `grep`ping/pattern searching in that class.