# Why class comparison in case doesn't work?

Tags: ruby

In general it is possible to compare two classes like this

```
x = "String"
puts "A string" if x.class == String
```

But, when `case` is used like this,

```
x = "String"
case x.class
  when String
    puts "A string"
end
```

It doesn't work. Why?

Update:

In the following case,

```
x = "String"
case x
  when String
    puts "A string"
end
```

it works. Does it mean, `case` converts classes into strings implicitly?

Comment: You are asking whether the `class` of `x` is a `String`. Well, obviously, it isn't, it's a `Class`. In the second example, you are asking whether `x` is a `String`, and that's the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comparison is done by comparing the object in the when-clause with the object in the case-clause using the `===` operator. That operator works as expected with literals, but not with classes. This means that if you want to do a `case ... when` over an object's class, this will not work.

```
>> 1 === 1
=> true
>> 1.class === 1.class
=> false
```

A good explanation and a small showcase on using the `===` on `Class` instances in Ruby is in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3908601/693387)

Comment: Particularly interesting in this regard: `1.class === 1` is `true`.

Comment: That's because `===` ist just a method that's been called on an instance and the instance can do whatever it sees fit. So obviously a `Fixnum` class matches its values inside the method `===`