# In Ruby, how do I switch on a variable containing a class object?

Tags: ruby, semantics

If I write this:

```
case v
when String
  puts :String
else
  puts :other
end
```

If I set `v` to `"some string"` I get 'String'.

If I set `v` to `String`, I get 'other'.

How am I supposed to 'switch' on a variable containing one of several class objects?

How does this honour the well-established computing principle of 'least surprise'?

Please don't tell me to monkey-patch the 'Class' class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby class types and case statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908380/ruby-class-types-and-case-statements)

Comment: The "least surprise principle" [doesn't say anything](http://www.artima.com/intv/ruby4.html) about **your** least surprise.

Comment: monkey-patch the 'Class' class

Comment: The `case` statement is very surprised to see an instance of `Class`.

Comment: monkey-patch the [`Module`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) class.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that [`===`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Object.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) (the test used by [`case`](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_expressions.html#S5)) can be confusing.

It's often called "case equality operator", but `===` is neither [reflexive nor symmetric nor transitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation), so it doesn't behave like an equality at all :

```
String === "test"
# true
"test" === String
# false
String === String
# false
String === Class
# false
Class === String
# true
Class === Class
# true
```

The best description I've read for `a === b` is from @JörgWMittag's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4467823/6419007) :

"*If I have a drawer labelled `a` would it make sense to put `b` in that drawer?*"

For your problem, you could write :

```
v = String
case v
when Class
  puts "#{v} is a Class, let's investigate some more"
  # another case, if statements or hash lookup...
else
  puts :other
end
```

Comment: `Class === Class #⇒ true` is worth to appear in the list :)

Comment: _"If I have a drawer labelled `String` would it make sense to put `String` in that drawer?"_ – still sounds reasonable.

Comment: _If I have a drawer labelled `Drawer` would it make sense to put `Drawer` in that drawer?_

Comment: The problem is the labelling. It's not just `a` (statically) but `a`'s definition of of `===`. So `when String` would become _“If I have a drawer labelled ‘instances of `String`’ would it make sense to put `String` in that drawer?”_

Comment: @Stefan: You're right, this definition doesn't always work. Still, it's hard to find something better. In `String === String` case, [eiko's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43187718/6419007) is a better fit : "Does String describe String? #=> false".

Answer (score 1):

> How am I supposed to 'switch' on a variable containing one of several class objects?

With [`Module#<=`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Module.html#method-i-3C-3D):

```
case v
when String then "instance of string"
when ->(c) { c <= String } then "class derived from String"
end
```

> How does this honour the well-established computing principle of 'least surprise'?

Perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `case` without an object:

```
case 
when v == String
  puts 'v is String class'
when v.is_a?(String)
  puts 'v is an instance of String'
else
  puts 'v is something else'
end
```

This resembles an `if`-`elsif`-`else` expression.

Comment: `v.is_a?(String)` does exactly what triple-equal does, doesn’t it? I understood the question as there is a need to check whether `v` is a `String` (instance of `Class`, `String`, or a subclass of `String`.)

Comment: @mudasobwa sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

Case expressions in ruby and some other functional languages are quite different from their imperative switch statement cousins.

As others have mentioned, case expressions use the `===` method, which is a pattern-defining method. In the `a === b` paradigm, `a` is a pattern which describes a collection of possible instances. `b` is an instance which potentially fits into that pattern / collection. Think of `a === b` as:

> does 'a' describe 'b'?

or

> does 'a' contain 'b'?

Once you understand this, `String === String #=> false` is not so surprising because `String` is an instance of `Class` so it fits into the `Class` pattern.

---

The other unique distinction between case expressions and switch statements is that case expressions are just that: *expressions*. Which means you can do cool stuff like this:

```
puts case v.name
  when "String"
    :String
  else
    :other
  end if v.is_a? Class
```

This code executes only if `v` is a class, then switches on `v.name` and `puts` whatever you want, based on the name of the class.

Because of ruby's nature as a duck-typed language, it's exceedingly rare to have a class in a variable and need to switch on it. If you're frustrated that `case` isn't as elegant as you had hoped, give us more context about your goal and we might be able to come up with an elegant solution which avoids switch all together.

Comment: Good answer. I lke `does 'a' describe 'b'` as a loose definition for `===`. It probably doesn't always work, but it might cover cases not covered by "If I have a drawer labelled `a` would it make sense to put `b` in that drawer?"